# What is difference between various mode in rabbit mq?

Tags: rabbitmq

What is difference between various mode in rabbit mq?

like mode:Reliable or mode:Fireforget

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two modes (reliable and 'fire and forget') is in the acknowledgment of messages. In the fire and forget-mode, messages can be lost when a TCP error occurs. With manually ACK'ed messages, this won't happen and messages lost in transmit will be requeued.

Source: [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

And an interesting demo on [message loss](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/10/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-rabbitmq-cluster).